# Run lambda container instance with root user privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My shared linux library need root privileges for running certain tasks but as per prerequisites in documentation says we should only relay on basic user access.

```
The default Lambda user must be able to read all the files required to run your function code. Lambda follows security best practices by defining a default Linux user with least-privileged permissions. Verify that your application code does not rely on files that other Linux users are restricted from running.
```

Is there a way for granting root user privileges to lambda container? Kindly provide the suggestions or help is appreciated.